# Get value from db and display value of selected item in another input text (Live search)

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is the situation, I'm using PHP programming and `MySQLi DB.` I want it to be able to search customer name real-time.

When I click the customer name that showed up as I key in letters, it automatically finds the customer's home address and set the value in address text field.

The customer name also will remain to stay in the search text field as the value before I can submit the form to insert it in another table.

Can someone teach me how to do that?

Code sample:

```
<form name="insert_form" method="POST">
  <label>Search Customer</label>
    <input type="text" name="searchCust"/>    
  <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="addressCust"/>
  <input type="submit" name="insert" value="INSERT"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 Autocomplete/suggestion input boxes using jQuery or Ajax with second box based on first selections with multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365185/2-autocomplete-suggestion-input-boxes-using-jquery-or-ajax-with-second-box-based)

Comment: I know it is duplicate question, but as you can see there's no solution I want for. Instead of switching to multiple selection, I want to do live search query. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: That's the same principle you only have to make it work for your own need. Another duplicate is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343712/php-mysql-autocomplete-from-database-not-getting-data-from-table?noredirect=1#comment87703852_50343712)

Comment: Check from the list here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=autocomplete+jquery